# Subsetting columns by another column and column index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get a certain subset of columns (defined by index range) of rows filtered by another column value. My data frame:

```
   A   B   C   D
0  11  b1  c1  d1
1  33  b2  c2  d2
2  22  b3  c3  d3
```

Here I can get all columns of rows by a column criteria:

```
df[df['A'] == 33]
```

Also, I can get certain columns of all rows by index:

```
df.iloc[:,0:2]
```

Now I want to combine the two along this logic (this doesn't work):

```
df[df['A'] == 33, 0:2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select columns by indexing with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df.columns[0:2])
Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')

df = df.loc[df['A'] == 33, df.columns[0:2]]
print (df)

    A   B
1  33  b2
```

because:

```
df = df.iloc[df['A'] == 33, 0:2]
```

> NotImplementedError: iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available

Answer (score 0):

We can combine them together :-)

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 33].iloc[:,0:2]
Out[464]: 
    A   B
1  33  b2
```

Or

```
df.iloc[(df['A'] == 33).nonzero()[0],0:2]
Out[471]: 
    A   B
1  33  b2
```